# Merging elevation values of multiple point shapefile

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, 3d, polyline-creation, z-value

In ArcMap I have thousands of points with elevation values from an aviation route. This route is stored in a multiple point shapefile. I made a polyline shapefile based on the route x, y locations. Is there any way to get the z values of these points into the polyline? I eventually want to illustrate the routes in 3D.

It's crazy that this seemingly common task isn't so obvious in ArcMap.

Comment: Are your points ordered or you created polyline by thousands of mouse clicks?

Comment: Do you need something complex like an average elevation on each line? If not, you could look into generating Z values for the line midpoints and/or endpoints using Spatial Analyst Extract (raster) Values tool, if you have a DEM.